# SQLTransientConnectionException after upgrading MariaDB connector

Tags: scala, jdbc, mariadb, slick, hikaricp

I've upgraded the ["org.mariadb.jdbc" % "mariadb-java-client"](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.mariadb.jdbc%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mariadb-java-client%22) connector from 1.5.9 to 1.6.0 and I'd started to fail while connecting to the DB due to timeout exceptions.

I'm using it with HikariCP 2.5.1 and Slick 3.2.0. If I rollback the change again to MariaDB connector 1.5.9 it successfully connects, and if I try to upgrade directly to 2.0.1, it fails with the very same error.

The thing is that based on [the 1.6.0 changelog](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-connector-j-160-changelog/), we shouldn't experiment any breaking change. But according to [the differences in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j/compare/1.5.9...1.6.0), it could have some more modifications than the ones specified in the changelog :/

Exception with a local DB:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: xxx.db - Connection is not available, request timed out after 5006ms.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:18)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.<init>(JdbcBackend.scala:439)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:47)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$class.acquireSession(BasicBackend.scala:218)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(BasicBackend.scala:239)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:156)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:118)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:92)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:108)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:341)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:193)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:430)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$500(HikariPool.java:64)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:570)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:563)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1020)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:481)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:103)
... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:392)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1013)
... 14 common frames omitted
```

Exception with a remote DB:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: xxx.db - Connection is not available, request timed out after 5003ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
    at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:18)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.<init>(JdbcBackend.scala:439)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:47)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
    at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$class.acquireSession(BasicBackend.scala:218)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
    at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(BasicBackend.scala:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am one of the mariadb developper*

In 1.6.0 version, "usePipelineAuth" option has changed the connection implementation.

> During connection, different queries are executed. When option is active those queries are send using pipeline (all queries are send, then only all results are reads), permitting faster connection creation.

That permit to saving network latency.

Disabling this option will probably solved your issue.

At the same time, i've create an [issue](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-474) on mariadb tracker.

Comment:    Thanks for your comment. As you said, setting it to false as a JDBC connection URL parameter makes the connection work properly again. In order to provide some more information just in case, if I upgrade until the last connector version (2.0.1) it still works as far as I maintain this flag disabled.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly looks like, at least in the local case, that:

- The port is mis-configured.  Or,
- The pool size exceeds the database maximum.  Or,
- The username/password is incorrect.  Or,
- The user does not have permission to connect to the server or the specified database.

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` is a socket level error.  Typically, this indicates that either there was no server running on the specified port, or the server is rejecting the connection for some other reason (security, etc).

You might double check all of the driver/datasource properties to verify that they are correct.  It might be useful if you could post your HikariCP configuration.